# All elements inheriting <body>’s styles

Tags: html, css

I have a style designated for `<body>`, but I also have a style for all other elements: `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc. However, all of the specific modifiers are still inheriting the `<body>`’s styles.

Here is the CSS for my `<body>`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: white;
}
```

And here is the style for my `<h1>`:

```css
.h1 {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-color: #000000
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Despite the modifier, `<h1>` still comes out white. If I remove the color from the `<body>` style, then the color is also removed from `<h1>`. The text for `<h1>`is also not aligned left.

For some reason it also affects the footer even though that is outside of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Did you notice that a semicolon is missing after the color code?

Comment: Does your h1 have the `h1` class?

Comment: You might want to post some more of your code so others can understand the issue better. A couple of issues, in addition to the missing semi-colon noted previously is that "font-color" is not used. Use "color" instead to affect the color of text. Also, an `H1` is a block level element which could influence the alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You've put a dot in front of your `h1` block, which makes it a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). That will apply to elements like `<div class="h1">`, which isn't what you want. Remove the dot to make it a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors), which will match every `<h1>` on your page.

> For some reason it also affects the footer even though that is outside of the `<body>` tag.

[The `<html>` element doesn't allow any content outside of the `<head>` or `<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html), so your browser is probably thinking "oh, this footer is supposed to be in the `<body>`; I'll just move it in there". That happens before the CSS is applied, so your `body` block is applied to the footer.

(Also, `font-color` isn't a CSS property, `color` is, and you're missing a semicolon after `#000000`.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, AuxTaco. While my typos were part of the error, it seems that (even when typed correctly) the problem persisted until I moved the <h1> modifier on a higher line (for example from line 80 to 60). Is this something that sounds correct? It surprised me because I'm still unsure if that matters. the <h1> is still below the <body>, but now my modifications are being shown.

Comment: @BrandonAV not trying to speak for AuxTaco, but I'm sure he'd agree with me about the need for you to post your HTML. It's silly to ask such specific questions about HTML (or any code for that matter) and not provide said code. You should familiarize yourself on [mcve]

Comment: @BrandonAV yes, we'd need to see exactly what you've written to be sure of what's going on. One troubleshooting step I'd take is to make sure you're writing valid HTML and CSS. Browsers won't (prominently) show you errors in your markup. They've been contending with dubious code for decades and will do their best to make sense of it without complaint. Run your code through an [HTML](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and a [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) validator to ensure you and your browser are on the same page.